# hiding parent element of a element passed as argument in the JavaScript function

Tags: php, javascript

I have a app where i have to show a timer for a event,and when the event is over , that timer (block containing it) should hide. i have set the CSS for the parent div element(that block) as the timer element has dynamic id(it has the id no of the events along with classname).

this is JavaScript code:

```
function GetCount(deal_year,deal_month,deal_date,deal_box)
    {
    dateFuture = new Date(deal_year,deal_month,deal_date,00,00,00);

   // alert(dateFuture); return false;

dateNow = new Date();                                   //grab current date
//alert(dateNow);
span = dateFuture.getTime() - dateNow.getTime();  //calc milliseconds between dates
delete dateNow;

// if date has passed
if(span <= 0){

          x=document.getElementById("dealbox");
          x.parentNode.getAttributeNode("style").value="display:none";

         } 
    else { // date is still good
           // convert from milliseconds to hr/m/s...
            // and save them in diff variable(code is long so avoided that)


       document.getElementById(deal_box).innerHTML="<span>"+out+"
  </span><br/><strong>days : hours :  minutes : seconds</strong>";


  setTimeout("GetCount('"+deal_year+"','"+deal_month
                       +"','"+deal_date+"','"+deal_box+"')", 1000);
```

Ans this is the php code

```
 if(strtotime("now") < strtotime($end_date)) { ?>                      

      <div class ="timer_box" id="timer" style="float:right; display: block;" >

         <b><div id="deal_box<?php echo $id; ?>"></div></b>
      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
    GetCount(<?php echo $timer_array[0]; ?>,<?php echo $timer_array[1]-1; ?>,<?php 
 echo $timer_array[2]; ?>,'<?php echo 'deal_box'.$id; ?>','<?php echo 'timer'; ?>');
      </script>  <?php } ?>
```

i tried hiding the parent block by using parentNode access of  DOM element passed into the function.
But it didn't work. I suspect that function is not able to access if of the parent through the element.
I tried every thing , but no help. so tried workaround of changining the class name of the element by javascript, but still think there shd be a better method,as i am noob n hopefully missing something.

Answer (score 0):

As your php script shows, you have a number(id) suffixed "deal_box", but you access it in javascript just using getElementById("deal_box")?

I mean, do you miss the id?
You fail to style a given Dom usually in two cases: 1, you don't get the Dom via correct selector at all; 2, there are some syntax problems in your style setting codes;

Suggest you use console.log() or other functions to trace your code.

Comment: well, i think that is local variable to the func and contains the value passed to it as its been declared . 
or i need to call it as such with the exact name as id?.
i tried working out with creating a class name to the div, and refreneceing my css to that class, but still the same.